# Which VNC to use?

Tags: windows-server-2008, vnc

Which VNC to use? Real, Ultra, Tight? The server machine is a Windows 2008 R2 running Exchange 2010 and there is need for only one administrator to connect to it. The client machine is going to be a Windows 7 one.

If the cost is small, even better.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

None. Use Windows's builtin Remote Desktop technology instead. It comes with both Windows Server and Windows 7, it's heavily optimized for Windows and in my experience, much nicer to use compared to VNC.

Answer (score 0):

The only advantage to VNC over RDP is the ability to log into the server or desktop as someone else is sitting there so you can demonstrate, teach or watch what someone is doing so you can correct them if need be, and there are better products than VNC to do it.

Use RDP as SvenW said. ;)